# Invalid argument while starting Cloud9 service on startup

Tags: systemd, services, daemon, init.d, chkconfig

I am trying to automate running Cloud9, by setting it as a service on Debian. This error stops me:

```
$ sudo service cloud9 start
Failed to start cloud9.service: Unit cloud9.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status cloud9.service' for details.
```

`systemctl status cloud9.service` output:

```
$ systemctl status cloud9.service
● cloud9.service - cloud9
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Probably it is due to misconfiguration in `/etc/systemd/system/cloud9.service`, which I just created:

```
[Unit]
Description=cloud9

[Service]
ExecStart=node server.js -w /home/user -l 0.0.0.0 -a admin:admin
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nobody
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/c9sdk

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How to create a simple startup script for the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first clue is that the diagnostic said to check the output of `systemctl status cloud9.service`, but you didn't mention doing that or sharing that output.

Perhaps it will tell you that the path the binary you pass to `ExecStart=` must be absolute.

Comment: The details from systemctl are already appended to the question.

Comment: This solved the problem, I used both absolute paths to node.js and the server.js

Comment: I was using ExecStart=~/script.sh, it wont work, and now I used an absolute path and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the "Invalid argument" here is the unit definition file itself. To debug it you can use:

`sudo systemd-analyze verify cloud9.service`

or in case of user's local service:

`sudo systemd-analyze --user verify cloud9.service`